# Uninstalling sitecore module

Tags: sitecore-client

In our environment some unintended module installed . Is there any way to uninstall module in sitecore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create **Anti Packages** using Sitecore Rocks.

You should do this **before installing Sitecore module**. It analyzes existing Sitecore items and files and put them in the Anti Package + creates scripts which will remove items and files which do not exist in Sitecore yet but do exist in the selected Sitecore Module package file.

So in fact Anti Package is a package which will revert your instance to what was there before installing your Sitecore Module package..

You can read more about Anti Packages here:

https://sitecoresandbox.com/2015/10/06/why-use-anti-package-functionality-with-sitecore-rocks/

https://www.techguilds.com/blog/2017/07/creating-an-anti-package-using-sitecore-rocks

Comment: Sitecore PowerShell Extensions comes with an anti-package Toolbox item seen here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/toolbox.html

Answer (score 5):

As Marek said your only option is using Anti Packages. This this is not an option then I'm afraid that out of the box there is no uninstaller for sitecore packages as described [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/916660).

One thing you can do is if you have the package used for installing you can extract it as a zip and remove the files and content items manually.

Of course each package is singular and have their own files/items.

Comment: If this is the only way to uninstall, we will do . Meanwhile I will raise ticket in sitecore support portal for any shared tool they have.

Comment: There is no tool from Sitecore for this.