# How to uninstall Sitecore Forms Extensions package?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I installed sitecore form extension-  http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/sitecoreformsextentions/9.1/developerdoc/install.html#configuration.  But now my form does not get saved.   Any idea to rollback or default to sitecore forms?

I do not wish to delete the files and items manually. Below is the error I get while saving the form  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed this and then removed it as well.  The code is easy to remove and the items are fairly isolated.  I found the root item paths by looking at the package and installed over them (overwrite) from a clean install of sitecore.  Packaged from the clean install and installed in my install.  That reset everything, but I had to get the right item paths first.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I will need to do that now.

Answer (score 4):

Sitecore doesn't provide an automated way for removing installed package using Installation Wizard. You can only remove packages manually if you have not created any anti-package using Sitecore rocks before installation. - [Uninstalling sitecore module](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8651/uninstalling-sitecore-module)

If you don't have anti-package then the only way is to follow steps described here - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/916660

Sitecore PowerShell Extensions comes with the anti-package feature as well - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/toolbox

Comment: Thanks for replying Mahendra. Yes, I was aware of it. However, I thought to check if someone has come up with any new idea .